# What's the maximum size of Web.config?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, error-handling, web-config

When I tried to open my SharePoint extended site, I received error 500. The error message was:

> Cannot read configuration file because it exceeds the maximum file size

My `web.config` file was just about 260 KB, because it had so many `<SafeControl>` entries in it. After removing some of the old entries, and getting the file down to 186 KB, my site started to load correctly.

My question:

- What is the maximum size of web.config?
- What can be done to avoid such problems in the future?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its not hard coded its defined in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Configuration\MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB
```

or on 64 Bit machines

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\InetStp\Configuration\MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB
```

The "cutoff point" by default, unless you configure the `MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB` appears to be 250Kb

Remember you can always split your web.config files into multiple little files to get around this issue,

Comment: This only works for IIS 7. With IIS 7.5 and later the setting is ignored.